# Why doesn't com.canon.cr2-raw-image conform to public.camera-raw-image according to UTTypeConformsTo?

Tags: macos, cocoa, uti

I am try to see whether a certain image is a RAW image file by getting the UTI for the file, then using `UTTypeConformsTo()` to see if the image's UTI conforms to "public.camera-raw-image", but when I try doing so, `UTTypeConformsTo()` returns false. Here is the code in question:

```
- (NSNumber*)bw_conformsToUTI:(NSString*)otherString
{
    Boolean conformsBoolean = UTTypeConformsTo((CFStringRef)self, (CFStringRef)otherString);
    NSNumber* conforms = [NSNumber numberWithBool:conformsBoolean];
    return conforms;
}
```

(the method is written as a category on NSString, and the lines are split apart like that because I was making sure in the debugger that there wasn't anything funny going on with converting from a Boolean to a BOOL and losing bits; conformsBoolean definitely comes back as all 0 bits)

If self is "com.canon.cr2-raw-image" and otherString is "public.camera-raw-image", I would expect this to return YES, but instead it results in NO. I tracked down where the "com.canon.cr2-raw-image" UTI is defined, and found it in /System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Library/RawCameraTypes.bundle/Info.plist where it does indeed specify that com.canon.cr2-raw-image conforms directly to public.camera-raw-image. I did notice that this is declare as an imported UTI and not an exported UTI, but since my application does recognize the declaration (as evidenced that I got that string in the first place via `UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag()`), I don't think that should make a difference.

Is there anything obviously wrong that I'm doing or misunderstanding here?

Comment: What do you get if you use `UTTypeCopyDeclaration` and `UTTypeCopyDeclaringBundleURL` on the former type?

Comment: Do the other raw types work as expected or is there just something strange about CR2?

Comment: HERP A DERP DERP - yeah, I was actually passing "public.camera.raw-image" instead of "public.camera-raw-image". Nothing to see here people, move along...